# Droplets and the Mac OS X Sandbox

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox

I've got several programs that can create droplets, e.g. mini-applications that when the user drag & drops files on them, will open the main application passing the dropped files and the settings stored in the droplet on to it. The main application will then process the files based on those settings.

With sandboxing I have several interesting problems, but the main one at the moment is that I can't pass the access privilege from the droplet to the main application, e.g.

1. user drags files onto droplet
2. droplet starts and is given access privileges to the files by the sandbox
3. droplet launches main application
4. main application attempts to read the files but sandbox blocks access to them..

Can anybody think of a way around this? Can bookmarks be shared or.. something.

Best regards,

Frank

Comment: Sadly I think this is just one of the many existing useful behaviours that the sandbox wasn't designed to take account of. I have several still outstanding, things that apps already do but aren't on the sandbox 'whitelist'. I suggest raising a radar with Apple and crossing your fingers.

It's things like this that make it increasingly likely that apps will start dopping off the App Store if Apple don't change their tune or extend the sandbox to all useful behaviours that apps in the App Store already do. Gatekeeper is a far more pragmatic approach.

Comment: No. It just doesn't seem to be possible.